# How to maintain Session and same channel in WCF WebApplication

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF Service, Hosted it in IIS and created a web application client for it.

Every thing works fine.

problem is, when I enable session in WCF service with all the required attributes it created one problem.

My service has several functions. function which I want to execute first is my Login functionality, so i set IsInitiating=true.

and IsInitiating=false on all other functions.

now from client side it works fine when i call the Login Function. but when i try to call other functions once the client is logged in it generate an exception , that function XYZ can not be call first because IsInitiating is set to fale;

I think the problem is every time when my page is posted back on the server it created a new instance of my wcf service which establish a new session with the server. how to maintain the same proxy for all the events in my web application?

Comment: Why do you use such architecture? It is a bad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very interesting link for you, which probably could solve your problem.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Sessions_in_WCF.aspx

Comment: Hey Denis,Well this article explained same things which i have read on other forums too.I have implemented it and consumed too. but my problem is at client side.
i have solve my problem by traditional way. I created a proxy and stored it in asp.net sessions. while i was thinking for another approach. i want to create a proxy and on every postback is there any way to have the same proxy instead of session?

Comment: Yes. Just cache the service proxy (client) and then retrieve it when you want to make a service operation invocation. Probably store it in the session or application object if you are using asp.net?